# jqGrid flicker in IE when hover over certain elements in TD

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, jqgrid, flicker

The background color of the TDs are changed when javascript changes the class of the row to '.ui-state-highlight'

There is a flicker when mouseout of DIVs and IMGs in the TD content, in IE, is there a way to prevent this flicker?

Comment: You should post a code example in your question which reproduce the problem. Then a solution of the problem or a workaround will be quickly found.

Comment: This is the hover state: [.ui-state-hover td], and it seems to be momentarily lost when hover over images and divs in the row, causing the TD to lose it's designated background color in milli-secs (only in IE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved the problem by using tr:hover in the css, instead of relying on the javascript to allocate the hover class. Not sure what was the root of the issue though.
I'm ok with the :hover since not supporting IE6.